# PayPal OAuth: 400 Error even after specifying Host

Tags: paypal, go, paypal-sandbox

I'm doing this one in golang, and I've been up just about the entire night trying to get it to work. My latest frustration is that I'm getting a 400 error despite the numerous headers I've dropped into my request.

```
 29     req.SetBasicAuth(app.id, app.secret)
 30     req.Header.Set("Host", "www.sandbox.paypal.com")
 31     req.Header.Set("Accept", "application/json")
 32     req.Header.Set("Accept-Language", "en_US")
 33     req.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
 34     req.Header.Set("Connection", "close")
```

I have auth set up, and every header I could think to add. I've pored over the documentation and have tried the poke it to see if it works approach as well. Heres the information I've been passing in the body with the post request

```
`{"grant_type": "client_credentials"}`

 42     req, err := http.NewRequest(
 43         "POST", 
 44         app.Endpoint + oauthEndpoint,
 45         strings.NewReader(`{"grant_type": "client_credentials"}`),
 46     )
```

If you need some more of the code just tell me. But I'm not super sure it'll be a whole lot of good. I wanted to make the post as general as possible as well.

**EDIT:**

So it seems that despite the fact I am specifying the grant_type in the payload manually it is failing because `grant_type` is not being recognized

```
{"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"grant_type is a required parameter"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem was my reader object, it should have been

```
strings.NewReader("grant_type=client_identifier")
```

Answer (score -1):

http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Header.Set

`Header.Set()` doesn't add a new header. You want `Header.Add()`. See the documentation link above.

Comment: It doesn't work just as similarly when I use Add. Also the headers were showing in the header mapping when I was using Set, I verified that over the course of debugging